# Flutter navigation to same page

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-getx

how can I achieve a functionality in my flutter application where I have a product details page and inside this page I have another product listing where similar products. So when I tap on that product tile I want to push same page with different product details? And I use Getx in my project..

example :

HomePage->ProductDetails->ProductDetails

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [arguments in GetX Route Management.](https://padymies.medium.com/flutter-getx-route-managment-b47635abd832)
**Don't forget to configure the routes to work correctly.**

Calling a route

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => Get.to(const PageOne(), arguments: {
  'id': Random().nextInt(1000).toString()
  }), // Passing data by using "arguments"
  child: const Text('Go to page One'),
),
```

And on the page that will receive the parameters

```
// Page One
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Page One'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          Get.arguments['id'] ?? 'Page One',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, i want routing to same page with different data but when i go back the previous data remains same.. just like any ecommerce application

Comment: Navigate to same page but treat as a different page

Comment: OK. But the example I gave is to do just that. It's a single page that receives the parameters and information according to the parameters that were informed, right?

Comment: You can send [parameters](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) also using a native way of Flutter.